# How to find "number of rows present in memory" in Python?

Tags: python

I'm defining a class that takes a file name as input, performs some basic string operations on each line, and returns the list of modified lines as output. One of the tasks is to *"return the number of rows in the file(and in-memory) when called the `len()` command."*

To return the number of rows in the file, I can simply initialize the `__len__()` function to return the number of rows in the file. But I want to know if there's anything related to the "number of rows present in the memory"?

**Edit:**

**Question:**
Design the data structure with the following properties:

1. The data structure is either callable or indexable. It will accept a single parameter, as an integer, and return the parsed contents of the row corresponding to the given index.
2. The data structure needs to return the number of rows in the file (and in-memory) when called with the python command `len(my_data_struct)`

Here's my code.

```py
import json
import re

class DataLoader(object):
    
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        with open(file_name) as file:
            rows = file.readlines()
            rows = list(map(self.__replace,rows))
        self.__data = self.__parse_rows(rows)
    
    def __parse_rows(self, rows):
        # helper function to return list of dictionaries
        data = list(map(json.loads, rows))
        return data
    
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        if isinstance(index,str):
            raise IndexError("Indices must be Integers")
        if isinstance(index,int):
            if index > len(self.__data):
                raise IndexError("Indices out of range")
            return self.__data[index]
                
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.__data)
  
    def __replace(self,row):
        # helper function to replace '_i' with 'index'
        return re.sub(r'_i','index',row)


data = DataLoader(filename)
```

Sample contents of the file.

```
{"_i": 0, "frame": "frame_000.png", "video": "video000", "value": 39, "labels": ["bird"]}
{"_i": 1, "frame": "frame_001.png", "video": "video000", "value": 33, "labels": ["frog", "dog"]}
{"_i": 2, "frame": "frame_002.png", "video": "video000", "value": 25, "labels": ["panda", "panda"]}
{"_i": 3, "frame": "frame_003.png", "video": "video000", "value": 28, "labels": ["dog", "dog"]}
```

Comment: The list is in memory. Does your class keep a reference to that list? If so, you could take it's len or sum the lens of its members.

Comment: " I can simply initialize the __len__() function after creating the class" huh? You mean *call* `len`? Or define `__len__`?

Comment: @tdelaney The class stores the lines of the file as a private attribute. I already defined the number of rows in the file as the output of the `len()` function. when you said, sum the lens of its members mean " take each row and calculate its size"?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I mean I defined `__len__` to return the number of rows in the file.

Comment: Let's see the code. That will help

Comment: If you read all of the lines from the file into your private variable and don't delete any lines, then the number of rows of the file is the same as the in memory list. Just return that number.

Comment: @DarkKnight I added the complete question and my code.

Comment: @tdelaney. Thank You.